# The data I entered in the TextField does not transfer to another label

Tags: ios, swift, label, textfield, viewcontroller

Hello guys can you help me, I have an app that has two ViewController and in the first VC I have four empty TextField and at the second VC I have four empty Labels that should receive new information and show I the label but my code doesn't work so could you help with this problem, I think something not right with my personalData

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var city: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mail: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      
    }
    @objc func edit() {
        print("Edit is done")
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "personalData" else { return }
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController else { return }
        destination.personalData = name.text ?? ""
        destination.personalData = age.text ?? ""
        destination.personalData = city.text ?? ""
        destination.personalData = mail.text ?? ""
    }
    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    

}
//////////////////////////////////////


import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    struct User{
        
    }
    var personalData = ""
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstProfileLabel.text = personalData
        secondProfileLabel.text = personalData
        thirdProfileLabel.text = personalData
        lastProfileLabel.text = personalData
        print("SecondVC", #function)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit,
                                                                target: self,
                                                                action: #selector(edit))
    
    }
    @objc func edit() {
             print("Edit is done")
         }
    @IBOutlet weak var firstProfileLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondProfileLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdProfileLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastProfileLabel: UILabel!
}
```

My mentor said that "The problem is with the variable personalData. The variable is of the stripe type and can store only one value.
If you want to pass values through a variable and not directly, you can create a structure, e.g. User with variables Name, Age, City, etc., and make personalData a User type and empty array."

But I don't understand how exactly I should write it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Start simple. Give your second view controller separate properties for each value you want to pass:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var name: String
    var age: String
    var city: String
    var mail: String
}
```

Then in your first view controller's `perpare(for:)` method, set each of those variables separately:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "personalData" else { return }
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController else { return }
        destination.name = name.text ?? ""
        destination.age = age.text ?? ""
        destination.city = city.text ?? ""
        destination.mail = mail.text ?? ""
    }
```

And rewrite your second view controller's viewDidLoad method to install each property into the correct field.

Once you've got that working, you can figure out how to instead pass all the string values in a single structure.

Hint:

Create a struct called something like UserInfo:

```
struct UserInfo {
    let name: String
    let age: String
    let city: String
    let mail: String
}
```

And then give your second view controller a property of type UserInfo, and set **that** in `prepare(for:)`